# Wordpress if custom field value is null previous posts' value is displayed

Tags: custom-fields, wordpress

I have this code with a loop that gives me some trouble and strange results.
This particular post type has a few custom fields which I put in an array. Everything works as expected, but if a field has no value it will take the value from the previous post within the loop.

Let's say I have these posts in Wordpress:

```
Post ID 10
custom_1 = 10
custom_2 = 20
custom_3 = 30

Post ID 20
custom_1 = 40
custom_2 = null
custom_3 = null
```

If I run my loop I get these results

```
Post ID 10
custom_1 = 10
custom_2 = 20
custom_3 = 30

Post ID 20
custom_1 = 40
custom_2 = 20 (instead of null)
custom_3 = 30 (instead of null)
```

Here's the short version of that loop:

```
$query = new WP_Query($query_arg);
if ($query->have_posts()) {
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $result[] = array(  
    "custom_1" => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_1', true),
    "custom_2" => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_2', true),
    "custom_3" => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_3', true)
        );
      }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.. tried pretty much everything, but nothing seams to work.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

UPDATE: 
Fixed it by changing the loop to this.

```
$query = new WP_Query($query_arg);
if ($query->have_posts()) {
while ($query->have_posts()) {
$query->the_post();

//set vars to "" which 'resets' the value with every new post in the loop
$custom_1 = "";
$custom_2 = "";
$custom_3 = "";

//set vars to the value of the custom fields
$custom_1 => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_1', true);
$custom_2 => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_2', true);
$custom_3 => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_3', true);

$result[] = array( 
"custom_1" => $custom_1,
"custom_2" => $custom_2,
"custom_3" => $custom_3
    );
  }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to how the MYSQL handles *null*. Null means an absence of value, so they do not get a space in the database, not even an empty one. An empty string however does show in the database.

Try the following

```
Post ID 10
custom_1 = 10
custom_2 = 20
custom_3 = 30

Post ID 20
custom_1 = 40
custom_2 = ""
custom_3 = ""
```

Comment: Thanks eevaa, not quite the solution but did point me into the right direction.